# Custom Ordering with NULL Values

Tags: postgresql, datamapper, ruby-datamapper

I have a DataMapper class Song (through PostgreSQL) that has the following property:

```
property :rating, Float, :required => false
```

Users can rate songs.
The problem is that I want users to browse available songs by rating. Say I have 5 songs, 3 of them have been rated, then something like this:

```
Song.all(:order => [:rating.desc])
```

will get me songs in the following order: {null, null, 10, 7, 6} or whatever. Is there a simple way to get these null values to the bottom of the ordering, so that my results will look like {10, 7, 6, null, null}.

I tried

```
Song.all(:rating.not => nil, :order => [rating.desc]) + song.all(:rating => nil)
```

but this combines the queries such that my resultset is nil.

An alternative of course is to default a null rating to something like -1, but due to some limitations I'd rather avoid this if possible.

Comment: What database are you connecting with? MySQL considers NULL values lesser than any other and it shows the order like `{10, 7, 6, null, null}`.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the position of `NULl` in `ORDER BY` clause. Check this [Sorting Rows](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/queries-order.html). I am not sure in datamapper but the sql will be like this

`SELECT select_list FROM table_expression ORDER BY sort_expression DESC NULLS LAST`